# Want to replace comma with decimal point in text file where after each number there is a comma in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, data-analysis, python-re

eg

```
Arun,Mishra,108,23,34,45,56,Mumbai
```

o\p I want is

```
Arun,Mishra,108.23,34,45,56,Mumbai
```

Tried to replace the comma with dot but all the demiliters are replaced with comma

tried `text.replace(',','.')` but replacing all the commas with dot

Comment: There is absolutely no way we can know which commas are actually decimal points, and which are commas.  You should fix your CSV data at its source.

Comment: Try `import re` `re.sub("([0-9]),","\\1.",text, count=1)`. But also I agree with Tim's comment.

Comment: And adding to Tim's comment, if your intended 3rd field is `108.23` and for some reason (locale setting?), it chose using `,` as separator, your CSV should've looked as `Arun,Mishra,"108,23",34,45,56,Mumbai` (Notice the embedded double quotes.)

Comment: no it will not look like Arun,Mishra,"108,23",34,45,56,Mumbai as in source file itself its comma

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex for these kind of tasks:

```
import re

old_str = 'Arun,Mishra,108,23,34,45,56,Mumbai'
new_str = re.sub(r'(\d+)(,)(\d+)', r'\1.\3', old_str, 1)
>>> 'Arun,Mishra,108.23,34,45,56,Mumbai'
```

The search pattern `r'(\d+)(,)(\d+)'` was to find a comma between two numbers. There are three capture groups, therefore one can use them in the replacement: `r\1.\3` (\1 and \3 are first and third groups). The old_str is the string and 1 is to tell the pattern to only replace the first occurrence (thus keep 34, 45).

Comment: If he is trying to update for multiple strings of same nature then it would be better to split and join the string than hardcoding regex

Comment: Why is that better? In my opinion this is more clear, what one wants to do. you can create your regex first and apply it later for performance. But what is better? better readable code? better performance? More pythonic? What do you define as better?

Comment: This would work.
A couple of points - (1) `,` need not be captured as `\2`. You can omit the parenthesis around it. (2) Since the entire `\1` and `\2` are in replacement, you could change the matching regex to just `\d` instead of `\d+`. A regex without `*`, `+` etc would be marginally faster in case many data iterations are expected.

Comment: Yes I agree, I made the regex first because I understood that the whole string contained numbers like (108,23,34,45) should read 108.23, 34.45 (both decimals) but it was only the first occurrence.

Comment: Oh, I see. In that case, having `+` makes sense. greedy matching. :-)

Comment: @3dSpatialUser I'm saying with assumption that he is trying to modify the csv. if for some row that digit is empty then it will modify next set. Of course in the given case using this regex is more efficient and I guess for iteration also we can change pattern to join 3rd and 4th element with '.' if its a digit

Comment: Arun,Mishra,108.23,34,45.56,Mumbai if we want this as output so this code is not working

Comment: The example is working fine, can you elaborate what is not working?

Answer (score 0):

It may be instructive to show how this can be done without additional module imports.

The idea is to search the string for all/any commas. Once the index of a comma has been identified, examine the characters either side (checking for digits). If such a pattern is observed, modify the string accordingly

```
s = 'Arun,Mishra,108,23,34,45,56,Mumbai'

pos = 1

while (pos := s.find(',', pos, len(s)-1)) > 0:
    if s[pos-1].isdigit() and s[pos+1].isdigit():
        s = s[:pos] + '.' + s[pos+1:]
        break
    pos += 1

print(s)
```

**Output:**

```
Arun,Mishra,108.23,34,45,56,Mumbai
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a plain CSV file as in your single line example, we can assume there are 8 columns and you want to 'merge' columns 3 and 4 together. You can do this with a regular expression - as shown below.
Here I explicitly match the 8 columns into 8 groups - matching everything *that is not a comma* as a column value and then write out the 8 columns again with commas separating all except columns 3 and 4 where I put the period/dot you require.

```
$ echo "Arun,Mishra,108,23,34,45,56,Mumbai" | sed -r "s/([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*)/\1,\2,\3.\4,\5,\6,\7,\8/"
Arun,Mishra,108.23,34,45,56,Mumbai
```

This regex is for your exact data. Having a generic regex to replace any comma between two subsequent sets of digits might give false matches on other data however so I think explicitly matching the data based on the exact columns you have will be the safest way to do it.

You can take the above regex and code it into your python code as shown below.

```
import re

inLine = 'Arun,Mishra,108,23,34,45,56,Mumbai'
outLine = re.sub(r'([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*)'
    , r'\1,\2,\3.\4,\5,\6,\7,\8', inLine, 0)
print(outLine)
```

As Tim Biegeleisen pointed out in an original comment, if you have access to the original source data you would be better fixing the formatting there. Of course that is not always possible.

Answer (score -1):

First split the string using s.split() and then replace ',' in 2nd element
after replacing join the string back again.

```
s= 'Arun,Mishra,108,23,34,45,56,Mumbai '
ls = s.split(',')
ls[2] = '.'.join([ls[2], ls[3]])
ls.pop(3)
s = ','.join(ls)
```

Comment: Now change the string to s= 'Arun,Mishra,banana,108,23,34,45,56,Mumbai'. The point here is to identify what needs to be changed by textual examination. Your answer relies on knowing exactly what the source string looks like

Answer (score -1):

It changes all the commas to dots if dot have numbers before and after itself.

```
txt = "2459,12 is the best number. lets change the dots . with commas , 458,45."

commaindex = 0

while commaindex != -1:
    commaindex = txt.find(",",commaindex+1)
    if txt[commaindex-1].isnumeric() and txt[commaindex+1].isnumeric():
        txt = txt[0:commaindex] + "." + txt[commaindex+1:len(txt)+1]
        
print(txt)
```

Comment: This does not work on the OPs sample. It replaces several commas with periods to produce ``Arun,Mishra,108.23.34.45.56,Mumbai``.

Comment: I answered it according to header. If we are 'assuming' there is columns he can use this at columns specially. We definitely can not now which of them are given as decimals. So yeah its not givin desired output because its not possible. we need more information